# Is using jwt tokens as correlation ID a good practice?

Tags: spring-boot, jwt, microservices, correlation

I need to trace a request across multiple microservices layers.

To do this best practices say to use a "correlation id", anyway in my app I'm already using a jwt token to handle several information.

Could the jwt token be a good candidate as correlation id or should I generate a separate one?

Comment: Did you look into using [Spring Cloud Sleuth](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-sleuth)? It's pretty much magic, drop in the dependency into your Microservices and it will start to maintain tracing headers for you. Assuming you do REST calls, if you are using SOAP through WebserviceTemplate then it needs some help with a custom interceptor.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you plan on generating a new JWT for each request, then a JWT is probably not the best place to store your correlation ID.  Here is one example of why this is the case.  Many websites, such as Facebook or Stack Overflow, issue long lasting JWT which either never expire, or expire very infrequently.  If you store the correlation ID in the claims section of the JWT, when it is created, then all requests made by that user would have the same correlation ID.  This could at least partially defeat the purpose of the correlation ID, because now different request flows might appear to be the same thing.

If you are using Java here, please look into using mapped diagnostic context (MDC), a framework which can seemlessly make a correlation ID in the request header available to your application for logging purposes, across all microservices.